# Select rows in table with condition of value of different column in same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, conditional-statements

**I have got table which represent items in orders with columns like this:**

```
--------------------------------------------------
| id     |  item_id   |   item_name  |  order_id  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1      |  12345     |   abcd       |  1001      |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2      |  55555     |   bbbb       |  1001      |
--------------------------------------------------
| 3      |  66666     |   cccc       |  1001      |
--------------------------------------------------
| 4      |  12345     |   abcd       |  1002      |
--------------------------------------------------
| 5      |  99999     |   yyyy       |  1002      |
--------------------------------------------------
| 6      |  12345     |   abcd       |  1003      |
--------------------------------------------------
| 7      |  98765     |   qqgg       |  1004      |
--------------------------------------------------
| 8      |  55112     |   ffdd       |  1004      |
```

I have an item with item_id = 12345 which is in several orders.

I would like to select all items, which fulfilled condition:

- **items are in same orders like item_id = 12345**

I try this SQL command but I think my approach is bad.

```
SELECT item_name   
FROM item_order
WHERE order_id IN (
      SELECT order_id 
      FROM item_order
      WHERE item_id = 12345
)
```

**Result, what I would like to get is:**

```
--------------------------------------------------
| id     |  item_id   |   item_name  |  order_id  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2      |  55555     |   bbbb       |  1001      |
--------------------------------------------------
| 3      |  66666     |   cccc       |  1001      |
--------------------------------------------------
| 5      |  99999     |   yyyy       |  1002      |
--------------------------------------------------
```

*Thanks for advice and sorry if the topic is confused.*

Comment: what u  want to fetch orders with `item_id =12345` ?

Comment: I want to fetch all different item in orders, where item with id 12345 occurs

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're just missing another part of your condition:

```
SELECT item_name   
FROM   item_order
WHERE   order_id IN (
        SELECT order_id 
        FROM item_order
        WHERE item_id = 12345
)
AND     item_id != 12345
```

Comment: Yes, You have right - but there is a problem behind first WHERE (i think) because result is not right

Comment: And query time is very long (ex 60 second), so is there other way to do it?